# Trying to use SQL data to multiply with other SQL data

Tags: c#, sql-server

So I am trying to use two different inputs from a user to get two different values then multiply them together to get an answer.

```
//code to get value 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Charges, Students from Subs where Subject_name='" + Subject + "'and Level='" + Level +  "'", con);
                        
//code to read and times the values
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Charges"]);
int NumS = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Subject_name"]);
int final = (Price*NumS) / 100;
status = final + "$";
```

Comment: What error are you trying to resolve?

Comment: I don't quite understand what's the problem if you could explain

Comment: im not quite sure myself but when i run the code at int Price = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Charges"]); it gives an error (System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.')

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
// Define **parametrized** query
string query = "SELECT Charges, Students FROM dbo.Subs WHERE Subject_name = @SubjectName AND Level = @Level;";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    // define the parameters and set value
    // I'm just *guessing* what datatype and what length these parameters are - please adapt as needed !
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SubjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Subject;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Level", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Level;
    
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int Price = reader.GetInt32(0);     // index = 0 is "Charges" of type INT
        
        // you are **NOT** selecting "Subject_Name" in your query - you therefore **CANNOT** read it from the SqlDataReader
        // int NumS = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Subject_name"]);
        int NumS = 1.0;
        
        int final = (Price * NumS) / 100;
        
        status = final + "$";    
    }
}
```

Points to ponder:

- You should also put your `SqlConnection con` into a proper `using (..) { ... }` block to ensure disposal
- You need to check the parameters - since you hadn't specified anything in your question, and also not posted any information about them, *I can only guess*
- Be aware - the `SqlDataReader` *might* (and in a great many cases **will**) return multiple rows - which you need to iterate over
- If you want to read out a column from the database table - it *must be* in the `SELECT` list of columns! You're trying to read out a column you're not selecting - that won't work, of course. ...